# How can I concatenate a string with variables in PHP?

Tags: php, string, concatenation

Here is my simple code logic just for the sake of simplicity. I want to concatenate string like: `10,11,12,13,14`, but it's just adding all the values
displaying wrong output as: `,100` it should display like: `10,11,12,13,14`
like other programming languages do.

```
<?php 

    // list is a string variable
    $list="";

    //total number of seats in a Bus
    $setnum=10;

    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        //i trying to concatenate string like 10,11,12,13,14 
        $list="$list".$i+$setnum.', ';
    }

    echo $list; 

?>
```

Comment: You are overwriting $list in your for loop because of one =. Use .= to add values to the string. More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: You should put `$i+$setnum` in parenthesis, `($i+$setnum)`. Also, `"$list"` only contains the variable, so using quotes is unnecessary. `$list.($i+$setnum).', '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// list is a string variable
$list = "";

// total number of seats in a Bus
$setnum = 10;
$list = "";
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
   // i trying to concatenate string like 10,11,12,13,14
   $list .= ($i + $setnum) . ', ';
}

echo $list;
```

Comment: Consider looking at the answers which include implode. It's a beter approach.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to concatenate strings is to add the strings to array and then `implode` them. Read more about [implode here](http://php.net/implode)

```
//total number of seats in a Bus
$setnum=10;

$list = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    //i trying to concatenate string like 10,11,12,13,14 
    $list[] =  $i+$setnum;
}

echo implode(',', $list);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [implode](http://php.net/implode) to avoid having a comma at the end and also you can use [range](http://php.net/range) to render an array with numerical values between two points.

So you could have something like

```
$setnum=10;
echo implode(',', range($setnum, ($setnum+10)));
```

You can see this snippet in action here: http://codepad.org/4nrD0Ajk

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside the `for`:

```
$list.= ($i+$setnum).', ';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// list is a string variable
$list = "";

// total number of seats in a Bus
$setnum = 10;

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) 
{
   // i trying to concatenate string like 10,11,12,13,14
   $list .= $i + $setnum . ',';
}

echo $list;
```